Running LLMs locally causing this error: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing
I have the following code to send a prompt request to a local LLM, ph-3. Although it shows the correct response in LM studio (check the image), on the VS I receive timeout error. Any help?
var phi3 = new CustomChatCompletionService();
phi3.ModelUrl = "http://localhost:1234/v1/chat/completions";

// semantic kernel builder
var builder = Kernel.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddKeyedSingleton<IChatCompletionService>("microsoft/Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct-gguf", phi3);
var kernel = builder.Build();

// init chat
var chat = kernel.GetRequiredService<IChatCompletionService>();
var history = new ChatHistory();
history.AddSystemMessage("You are a useful assistant that replies using a funny style and emojis. Your name is Goku.");
history.AddUserMessage("hi, who are you?");

// print response
var result = await chat.GetChatMessageContentsAsync(history);
Console.WriteLine(result[^1].Content);



You don't necessarily need a Custom Chat Completion Service to consume your local phi-3 Model.
You can use the OpenAI Connector with the experimental endpoint override parameter to your LMStudio Http API
var builder = kernel.CreateBuilder()
    .AddOpenAIChatCompletion(
        modelId: "phi3", 
        endpoint: new Uri("http://localhost:1234"), 
        apiKey: null)
    .Build();


I faced a similar issue with local Ollama. I created a new HttpClient and passed it to the AddOpenAIChatCompletion function.
private Kernel BuildKernel(string modelid, string ollamauri)
{
    //Create a separate HttpClient to avoid timeout issues
     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
   {
     Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
   };
    //Create Kernel builder
    var builder = Kernel.CreateBuilder();
    #pragma warning disable SKEXP0010
    return builder
        .AddOpenAIChatCompletion(// We use Semantic Kernel OpenAI API
            modelId: modelid,
            apiKey: null,
            endpoint: new Uri(ollamauri), // With Ollama OpenAI API endpoint
            httpClient:httpClient) 
        .Build();
}

